# How to get Status of the executed application in parent process called through exec?

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, embedded-linux

I am developing a simple application which does the following things :

1. The main application will have child process where in am invoking the application through exec call. this application is actually performing the Firmware download operation. 
   eg.  execl("/usr/bin/fwdownload","fwdownload", "args", NULL);
2. In the parent process , I will again fork it so that i will have again child process . In this child process, I am invoking Xmodem utility to receive the firmware image file from the local machine. I write the received packets to the named fifo file ( created using mkfifo ) . This named fifo file will be accessing by "fwdownload" application to read the packets to flash the firmware.
3. So again In the parent process, I check for the status of the "fwdownload" application when xmodem file transfer is happening .

Problem I am facing here is :

1. I am not able to get the status of the "fwdownload" application in the parent process when it fails . How to get this status . Tried all the possible ways
2. How do I kill the xmodem utility invoked through second child process whenever I get the failure status from the "fwdownload" app? .

Pseudo code:

```
void SIGTERM_Handler(int signal)
{
    exit(0);  // Kill the Xmodem utility
}


int main()
{
   pid_t cpid_1, cpid_2 ; 

   cpid_1 = fork();

   if( cpid_1 == 0 )  // child process
   {
       execl("/usr/bin/fwdownload", "fwdownload", NULL);
       printf("exec Failed");
       exit(FAILED);
   }
   else   // Parent process
   {
        cpid_2 = fork();   
        if( cpid_2 == 0 )
        {

            mkfifo("/tmp/fifo_file");
            signal(SIGTERM, SIGTERM_Handler);
            execl("/bin/rx", "rx", "/tmp/fifo_file", NULL);  // fifo_file
            printf("exec failed");
            exit(FAILED);       
        }
        else
        {
            wait_status = waitpid(cpid_1, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);

            if( WIFEXITED(status))
            {
                kill(cpid_2, SIGTERM);
                printf(" FW Download app is exited \n");                    

            }       
        }           
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why a FIFO and not a pipe between the child processes? Or just a normal file? I personally would never assume the firmware transfer succeeds, and would always want the firmware installer application to detect if the firmware download failed or was interrupted (due to, say, network outage, or something). If the firmware installer always reads the entire image into memory (because it has a checksum somewhere in it), it really should support reading the data from standard input. If not, I'd for sure use a temporary file and separate sha256sum checksums...

Comment: I am not using normal file because fwdownload app expect file transfer to be in packet wise transaction.  I dont have any reasons why we are not using pipe . Do we have any extra benefit if we use normal pipe rather than FIFO file ? .

Comment: Using a pipe has several advantages. If the download application dies/exits, the installer will detect it by next `read()` returning 0. If the installer dies/exits, the download application will get -1 from the next `write()`, with `errno == EPIPE`. If using a FIFO, the other end will block until the other end is open, too, and there is always a risk of some other process intervening (by also opening the FIFO); also, the FIFO filesystem object must be created and deleted as needed. Simply put, a FIFO is more complex with more risks, with no upsides in this use case.

Comment: Thank you so much . Yes you are right . In my case,  I suspect that there is a dead-lock is happening . When a process for writing to the FIFO started , other process reading from the same FIFO must have been executed at the same time . But in my case , Second process ( reading from the FIFO ) is exiting or returning which will make the first process in Blocking state. 
Hence , You suggest me that , If we use pipe , this case would not happen ? .

Comment: If both programs explicitly close the pipe before exiting, that should not happen. The writer (downloader) will block until the reader (installer) reads the data (except that each pipe has a buffer of at least 512 bytes that can be written to "immediately", as long as the other end of the pipe is still open); the reader will block until the writer either closes the pipe, or writes more data. Have you considered writing a minimal test program -- say, one where the childs exit if they see a specific character in the data, sleep on some others, but otherwise don't do real work?

Comment: Ok thanks again . I would try to simple application to test the same.

One more thing I would like to ask you . Have you ever used , Xmodem utility in linux ( rz/rx ) ? .

Comment: No. (I probably have used the old DOS counterparts, but it's been at least 25 years, and I've forgotten the details anyway.) Of course, the [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) itself is straightforward, and includes checksumming for each packet. Do you know if in your use case, you have A) RAM, or B) writable disk space, enough to hold the entire download? If so, it'd simplify everything *a lot*. I worry about the cases where your installer starts installing the new firmware image, but the download gets interrupted -- a partially overwritten firmware has zero chance of working.

Comment: Thanks Buddy for all the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

To get the status of a terminated process you can use the WEXITSTATUS(status) macro. This macro will give you the code returned by the child process.

Also catching a signal before calling execl is useless because (extract from the execve man page):

> The dispositions of any signals that are being caught are reset to the default (signal(7)).

In your case you get this code:

```
int main()
{
   pid_t cpid_1, cpid_2 ; 

   cpid_1 = fork();

   if( cpid_1 == 0 )  // child process
   {
       execl("/usr/bin/fwdownload", "fwdownload", NULL);
       printf("exec Failed");
       exit(FAILED);
   }
   else   // Parent process
   {
        cpid_2 = fork();   
        if( cpid_2 == 0 )
        {

            mkfifo("/tmp/fifo_file");
            //signal(SIGTERM, SIGTERM_Handler);
            execl("/bin/rx", "rx", "/tmp/fifo_file", NULL);  // fifo_file
            printf("exec failed");
            exit(FAILED);       
        }
        else
        {
            wait_status = waitpid(cpid_1, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);

            if( WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0)
            {
                kill(cpid_2, SIGTERM);
                printf(" FW Download app is exited \n");                    

            }       
        }           
    }  
}
```

Comment: As per my understanding , signal() system call would register for the specified the signal for that process  and corresponding signal_handler will handle if that signal occurs. 
As you mentioned that signal( ) is not intended for catching the signal . This is to just register for the particular signal.
Please correct me If I am wrong my pal .